# Google maps styling in Bangkok

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to style Google Maps for Bangkok, but for some reason I am unable to style any of the public transportation routes (skytrain) or remove them completely. Am I doing something wrong or should I report this as a bug?

Playing with the visibility settings seems to only affect the station indicators, not the lines themselves.

**Edit: Steps to replicate issue:**

1. Open Google Styling Wizard:
   http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter
2. Navigate to Bangkok
3. Select Feature Type Transit
4. Change any styling (for example, visibility). The stations themselves disappear, but the lines stay.

Comment: What is the styling you have tried that you believe should have worked but didn't?  What does the code for your map look like?  Can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Hard to create a fiddle without using my own Maps API Key. Will edit the post to include a guide on how to recreate the issue with Google Maps Styling Wizard

Comment: API keys are not required (at least for styled maps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this and figured I'd share. It seems that you can only style the Bangkok skytrain lines if you first set

```
{"stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}
```

and then set the relevant styles, i.e:

```
{"featureType": "transit","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"},{saturation: -100},{lightness: 25}]}
```